# Youtube videos sticking to the screen

Tags: gnome, flash, youtube

I can watch youtube movies just fine, but sometimes they stick to the screen when I close them. When that happens, I can't see them. But, when something black comes over that area of the screen, the black changes into the frozen image of the youtube video. For some reason, it's not on the screenshot. It's kind of hard to explain what I mean without images, but I hope you'll understand.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on windows 7 using chrome :/

Answer (score 0):

Try running this on a terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/adobe
sudo bash -c "echo 'OverrideGPUValidation = 1' >> /etc/adobe/mms.cfg"
```

Flash Player has a freeze problem on ubuntu.

Comment: has anyone tried this?